# Displaying Dictionary Data

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Okay, so I got one part of my college work helped with, however now there's just one more step to do: Displaying the data.  Now, the assignment in question has the user being able to search for a product by ID number, displaying it's description, daily, weekly, monthly rental rates, and the quantity in stock into the TextBox controls already on the form, the data coming from a dictionary in another class.  This is also for editing purposes (see note below).  In addition, I'm also having an issue with adding the ID variable into the ComboBox's collection when reading in and adding items to the Dictionary, which should be a simple fix, I'm sure, but I just would like some help with remembering what it is, that's all.

Here is the code for frmMain that contains the code for the display button (Don't mind how rough it looks, please):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmMain

Dim dItem As New Inventory
Dim filePath = ofdOpenFile.FileName

Public Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim ID As String = cboID.Text
    Dim Desc As String = txtDescription.Text
    Dim DRate As Double = txtDaily.Text
    Dim WRate As Double = txtWeekly.Text
    Dim MRate As Double = txtMonthly.Text
    Dim Quantity As Integer = txtQuantity.Text

    dItem.addItem(ID, Desc, DRate, WRate, MRate, Quantity)
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    Dim ID As String = cboID.Text

    dItem.removeItem(ID)
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    ' Display data should go here
End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If ofdOpenFile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim FileInfo As New InventoryFile
        FileInfo.RFile(filePath, dItem)
        cboID.DataSource = dItem.returnKeys()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Here's the code for my dictionary class:

```
Public Class Inventory

Public ItemInventory As New Dictionary(Of String, Item)

Public Function iItem(ByVal key As String) As Item
    Return ItemInventory(key)
End Function

Public Sub addItem(ByVal item As String, ByVal Desc As String, ByVal DRate As Double, ByVal WRate As Double, _
                   ByVal MRate As Double, ByVal Quantity As Integer)
    With ItemInventory
        .Add(item, New Item(item, Desc, DRate, WRate, MRate, Quantity))
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub removeItem(ByVal item As String)

    With ItemInventory
        .Remove(item)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function returnKeys() As String()
    Dim Keys() As String

    With ItemInventory
        Keys = .Keys.ToList.ToArray
    End With

    Return Keys
  End Function
End Class
```

I believe that should be it.  I can add in the other classes as needed, but otherwise, the Dictionary has the key and the 'Item', that being a reference to the Item class, which contains the additional data that's needed to be displayed (there's a series of variables in my 'Add' code that should answer as to what all is in the 'Item' class).  How exactly should I reference the dictionary to display the entries?

Answer (score 1):

seems like there are several questions there... for adding to a combo, there are several ways. One way would be to add a .ToString method to the Inven class which returns the Description. Then when you add the Inventory ITEMS to the cbo, you are adding OBJECTS but the cbo will use the ToString  method to display worthwhile text.

```
for each kvp as KeyValuePair In ItemInventory 
   theCbo.Items.Add(kvp.Value)        ' adding Inven OBJECTS to it
next kvp
```

Another easy way is to make the dictionary the datasource for the cbo:

```
theCbo.DataSource = New BindingSource(ItemInventory, Nothing)
theCbo.ValueMember = "Key"
theCbo.DisplayMember = "Value"    ' still relies on ToString
```

Since they are OBJECTS in the cbo.Items, you can easy find the one they select:

```
thisID = cbo.SelectedItem.ID
```

This could be passed to a new `DisplayItem` method in Inventory which would post the data to the form controls:

```
dInven.Display(thisID)

Friend Sub Display(theID as String)   '
    If ItemInventory.ContainsKey(theID) Then
       With theForm
           .tbDescr.Text = ItemInventory(theId).Description
            ...
       End With
    End If
End Sub
```